# What's the correct way to pass parameters to JavaScript or jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like this example:

```
var variable = '';
function myFunction(param){
   variable = param;
   alert(variable);
}
```

or like this:

```
function myFunction(param){
   alert(param);
}
```

Comment: It depends on how you intend to use it

Comment: But you can use function parameters like any variable.

Comment: What on earth is going on in that first example?  Why would you use a global variable inside a function for something that's passed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason to do it the way you show in your first example is if you NEED to store the parameter persistently in a way that will survive from one invocation of the function to another.  If you don't need that, then the second way is much, much cleaner and doesn't introduce  unnecessary variables and doesn't pollute the higher scope.

I should add that arguments to functions work just like local variables.  There is no reason to assign them to other variables just to use them.  You can use the argument variable directly just fine.